# Find a Lipschitz constant for the function 5 - sin(y)

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

How do i find the Lipschitz constant for the function:

y' = 5 - sin(y), 5 ≤ x ≤ 9, y(0) = 0.95

Not sure how to approach this so any help would be really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: you should use $$f(x_2,y)-f(x_1,y)$$ or $$f(x,y_2)-f(x,y_1)$$

Comment: Since $y'(x) \le 3$ for any $x$, I would say that $3$ is a Lipschitz constant for $y$.